# Настройка CodeIgnitor`а для работы в стеке LAMP под Debian

Tags: debian, codeigniter, lamp

**Помогите с настройка codeignitor на Lamp в Debian**
[image: не работает codeignitor]

вот текст ошибки

---

> > Warning: require_once(/var/www/market-tat.loc/public_html/system/core/CodeIgniter.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/market-tat.loc/public_html/index.php on line 315
> >
> > Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/market-tat.loc/public_html/system/core/CodeIgniter.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/market-tat.loc/public_html/index.php on line 315

---

Немогу понять почему выходит ошибка, единственное что нет **/usr/share/pear**  но вот **.:/usr/share/php** *существует* , тогда почему ошибка !?

Может есть ошибки с доступом к ним?
Но, разрешон полный доступ к файлам CI через

> > $chmod 777 dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > ***Link original ask ->>***http://idroot.net/tutorials/how-to-install-codeigniter-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Install CodeIgniter on Ubuntu 14.04

Step 1. First make sure that all your system packages are up-to-date by running these following apt-get commands in the terminal.

> > sudo apt-get update
> >     sudo apt-get upgrade

Step 2. Install LAMP server.

A Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP server is required. If you do not have LAMP installed, you can follow our guide here.

Step 3. Install CodeIgniter.

Download the latest stable version of CodeIgniter, At the moment of writing this article it is version 3.0.1:

> > cd /var/www/
> >     wget https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/archive/3.0.1.zip
> >     unzip 3.0.1.zip
> >     mv /var/www/CodeIgniter-3.0.1 /var/www/yourdomain

Change the ownership of that directory and files:

> > chown -R www-data: /var/www/yourdomain

Step 4. Configure MySQL Database for CodeIgniter.

By default, MySQL is not hardened. You can secure MySQL using the mysql_secure_installation script. you should read and below each steps carefully which will set root password, remove anonymous users, disallow remote root login, and remove the test database and access to secure MySQL.

> > mysql_secure_installation

Next we will need to log in to the MySQL console and create a database for CodeIgniter. Run the following command:

> > mysql -u root -p

This will prompt you for a password, so enter your MySQL root password and hit Enter. Once you are logged in to your database server you need to create a database for the CodeIgniter software:

> > mysql> CREATE DATABASE codeigniter_db;
> >     mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on codeigniter_db.* to 'codeigniter_user'@'localhost' identified by 'YoUrPaS$w0rD';
> >     mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
> >     mysql> exit

Next, you need to change the database connectivity settings to the settings needed to access your newly created database:

> > nano /var/www/yourdomain/application/config/database.php

Find the following lines:

> > $db['default'] = array(
> >            'dsn'   => '',
> >            'hostname' => 'localhost',
> >            'username' => 'codeigniter_user',
> >            'password' => 'YoUrPaS$w0rD',
> >            'database' => 'наша_бд',
> >     );

Also, you need to edit the following file:

> > nano /var/www/yourdomain/application/config/config.php

Find the following line to set your base URL:

> > $config['base_url'] = 'хттп://yourdomain.com';

Save the file and close it.

Step 5. Configure Apache2 web server.

Edit the virtual host file and change the document root to point to /var/www/yourdomain:

> > nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
> >
> > > VirtualHost *:80>
> >
> > ServerAdmin admin@yourdomain.com
> >
> > DocumentRoot /var/www/yourdomain/
> >
> > ServerName yourdomain.com
> >
> > ServerAlias ввв.yourdomain.loc
> >
> > > Directory /var/www/yourdomain/>
> >
> > Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
> >
> > AllowOverride All
> >
> > Order allow,deny
> >
> > allow from all
> >
> > > /Directory>
> >
> > ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/yourdomain.com-error_log
> >
> > CustomLog /var/log/httpd/yourdomain.com-access_log common
> >
> > > /VirtualHost>

Save and close the file once you are done. Restart the Apache service for the changes to take effect:
service apache2 restart
1

> > service apache2 restart

Step 6. Access CodeIgniter.

CodeIgniter will be available on HTTP port 80 by default. Open your favorite browser and navigate to ://yourdomain.loc or ://server-ip and complete the required the steps to finish the installation. If you are using a firewall, please open port 80 to enable access to the control panel.

Congratulation’s! You have successfully installed CodeIgniter. Thanks for using this tutorial for installing CodeIgniter on Ubuntu 14.04 system. For additional help or useful information, we recommend you to check the official CodeIgniter web site.

Comment: Ссылка на оригинал 
http://idroot.net/tutorials/how-to-install-codeigniter-on-ubuntu-14-04/